Differences between SPSPERS#10 and SPSPERS#12 OneDrive Site templates
Does anyone know the differences between these OneDrive site templates?

SPSPERS#10 Storage And Social SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space
SPSPERS#12 JIT OneDrive Business

Today I encountered a tenant where some of the OneDrive sites have the SPSPERS#12 template. I never saw this one before wanted to know if it's any different from the SPSPERS#10 template.
Code I used to see the templates:
$tenant = "redacted"   
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://$tenant-admin.sharepoint.com" -UseWebLogin

$personalSites = Get-PnPTenantSite -IncludeOneDriveSites -Filter "Url -like 'https://$tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/'" |
Select Title, URL, Owner,Template, LastContentModifiedDate, StorageUsage, Status 

The only information on the Internet about these templates is not very helpful:
SPSPERS#10 Storage And Social SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space
SPSPERS#11 Consumer OneDrive 
SPSPERS#12 JIT OneDrive Business
SPSPERS#13 JIT OneDrive Consumer

Any information is very appreciated.

These two templates are designed for individual users’ personal OneDrive for Business sites. There doesn't seem to be any difference between the two templates, both of which are used to provides a private storage space for users to store and manage their files.

I can see some small differences on the Site Contents page. Number of default lists and libraries is different. Also, I suspect there might be more differences in terms of features, property bag properties and such.
